# SQL Server return different values if use a float type

Tags: c#, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, i had a example:

```
DECLARE @baz float;
SET @baz = 7.19973;
select ROUND(@baz, 5, 1) --> 7.19972
select ROUND(7.19973, 5, 1) --> 7.19973
```

Please help me explain why the above query return to 7.19972 ? . And
how to build a function like ROUND function on c# ?

Comment: please read : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: No need to build a function of round in C# it is built in [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the third argument.  Although the function is called `round()`, it actually truncates the value when the third argument is anything but 0.  (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx).)

What is happening?  A constant with a decimal point is a decimal value in SQL Server.  The assignment to a float is approximate.  In this case, the value must be something like:  `7.19972999997`.  This is passed to `round()` as a `float` and the third argument causes the value to be truncated to `7.19972`.

When you call:

```
select ROUND(7.19973, 5, 1)
```

The value is passed as a `decimal`.  There is no conversion to `float` so the decimal values are exact and the truncation returns the original value.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Now i want to convert SQL Server to another database. So i need to build a function like that, you can help me implement it?

Comment: @DatTruong . . . If you have a question about another database, then you should ask another question.  This answer would appear to answer this specific question.

Comment: Can you help me explain below case : select ROUND(7.19977, 5, 1) --> 7.19977

Comment: The first argument is a decimal passed into `ROUND()`, not a float.